# How to insert data from radiobutton and combobox to table in MS Sql

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, insert, radio-button

I am working on building an application with c# WF. I created an employee table in MS sql database. I have two radio buttons for gender (male and female). Depending on how users click on radio button (male or female), I would like to write sql statement that can insert one of the two radiobutton choices. Same thing applies to combobox. Upon user's choice of selection to data from combobox, I want data to save in table. I googled the questions, and didn't come out the right one. There is one posted here at Feb 7th. Question was unaswered. Not sure how to write codes for combobox.

```
("INSERT INTO Employeess(EmpID,FirstName,LastName,Salary,desgnation,gender) 
                        values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox2.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox3.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox4.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox5.Text + "','" + 
                                     **radioButton1.Checked+"'** )");
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what is the column data type of `gender`?

Comment: user a flag/Id to save in DB....

Comment: Column data type is varchar(6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely changed my code and it works. I am using with sqlcommand.paramemters.addwithvalue. When I googled the solutions, I found out that previous coding is vlunerable for sql injection. Thank for help.Below is my complete code for saving data into database from textboxes, combobox and radio buttons.

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {


            DataValidateAndDateFormat();

            string strGender;
            string strConnectionString = @"Data Source = KK\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = SSPI; Initial Catalog = JeanDB";

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            cn.Open();

            string strEmpID = txtEmpID.Text.Trim();
            string strFirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
            string strLastName = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
            string strDesignation = txtDesignation.Text.Trim();
            int iSalary = Convert.ToInt32(txtSalary.Text.Trim());
            string strAddress = txtAddress.Text.Trim();
            int iZipCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtZipCode.Text.Trim());
            int iPhone = Convert.ToInt32(txtPhone.Text.Trim());
            string strEmail = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
            DateTime dtDOB = dtPickerDOB.Value;
            string strNationality = comboNationality.SelectedItem.ToString();

            if (rbMale.Checked)
                strGender = "Male";
            else
                strGender = "Female";

            string strUserName = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
            string strPassword = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

            string query = "INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Designation, Salary, Address, ZipCode, Phone, Email, DOB, Nationality, Gender, Username, Password)VALUES(@strEmpID, @strFirstName, @strLastName, @strDesignation, @iSalary, @strAddress, @iZipCode, @iPhone,@strEmail, @dtDOB, @strNationality, @strGender, @strUserName, @strPassword)";
            SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            InsertCommand.Connection = cn;

            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strEmpID", strEmpID);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strFirstName", strFirstName);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strLastName", strLastName);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strDesignation", strDesignation);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"iSalary", iSalary);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strAddress", strAddress);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"iZipCode", iZipCode);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"iPhone", iPhone);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strEmail", strEmail);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"dtDOB", dtDOB);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strNationality", strNationality);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strGender", strGender);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strUsername", strUserName);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strPassword", strPassword);

            InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("New Employee's Data has been added successfully");

            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bit data type for your column. Then you can insert `radioButton1.Checked` checked value directly using SQL parameters.

since you haven't provide full code, try

```
("INSERT INTO Employeess(EmpID,FirstName,LastName,Salary,desgnation,gender) 
                        values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox2.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox3.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox4.Text + "','" + 
                                     textBox5.Text + "'," + 
                                      (radioButton1.Checked ? "1" : "0") +" )");
```